# SwiftUI: observe @Environment property changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was trying to use the SwiftUI `@Environment` property wrapper, but I can't manage to make it work as I expected. Please, help me understanding what I'm doing wrong.

As an example I have an object that produces an integer once per second:

```
class IntGenerator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var newValue = 0 {
        didSet {
            print(newValue)
        }
    }

    private var toCanc: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        toCanc = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .map { _ in Int.random(in: 0..<1000) }
            .assign(to: \.newValue, on: self)
    }
}
```

This object works as expected since I can see all the integers generated on the console log. Now, let's say we want this object to be an environment object accessible from all over the app and from whoever. Let's create the related environment key:

```
struct IntGeneratorKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = IntGenerator()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var intGenerator: IntGenerator {
        get {
            return self[IntGeneratorKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[IntGeneratorKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can access this object like this (for example from a view):

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.intGenerator) var intGenerator: IntGenerator

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(intGenerator.newValue)")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, despite the `newValue` being a `@Published` property I'm not receiving any update on that property and the `Text` always shows 0. I'm sure I'm missing something here, what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: I’m confused, why using environment vs environmentobject? You can use that and a publisher

Comment: @ColinWhooten `EnvironmentObject` is for injecting objects in your view hierarchy and having those objects available in all the views inside your view hierarchy. `Environment` is not strictly related to views. It's just to create a global dependency in your project. When you create an `Environment` dependency you can access that dependency from all the entities in your app (not just views). So, I wanted to understand if I could observe `Published` properties inside an `Environment` object.

Comment: I had the same problem but was using `EnvironmentObject` with `ObservedObject` inside. View didn't update unless I changed `ObservedObject` to `Published`. Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Environment` gives you access to what is stored under `EnvironmentKey` but does not generate observer for its internals (ie. you would be notified if value of EnvironmentKey changed itself, but in your case it is instance and its reference stored under key is not changed). So it needs to do observing manually, is you have publisher there, like below

```
@Environment(\.intGenerator) var intGenerator: IntGenerator

@State private var value = 0
var body: some View {
    Text("\(value)")
        .onReceive(intGenerator.$newValue) { self.value = $0 }
}
```

and all works... tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Comment: This is amazing! How did this cross your mind?

Comment: How does Apple achieve this for its event such as  `colorScheme`, `horizontalSizeClass`, etc?

Comment: Great answer @Asperi, but could you please explain more why the view won't be redrawn automatically?

Comment: @anders, because those have value semantics so the value change will be detected by the view. In the above example, `IntGenerator` is a reference to an object and that reference doesn’t change – only a property of the object changes. This will not be detected automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a definitive answer for how exactly Apple dynamically sends updates to it's standard `Environment` keys (`colorScheme`, `horizontalSizeClass`, etc) but I do have a solution and I suspect Apple does something similar behind the scenes.

**Step One)** Create an `ObservableObject` with an `@Published` properties for your values.

```
class IntGenerator: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var int = 0
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .map { _ in Int.random(in: 0..<1000) }
            .assign(to: \.int, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
}
```

**Step Two)** Create a custom `Environment` key/value for your property. Here is the first difference between your existing code. Instead of using `IntGenerator` you'll have an `EnvironmentKey` for each individual `@Published` property from **step 1**.

```
struct IntKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = 0
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var int: Int {
        get {
            return self[IntKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[IntKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

**Step Three - UIHostingController Approach)** This is if you are using an App Delegate as your life cycle (aka a UIKit app w/ Swift UI features). Here is the secret to how we'll be able to dynamically update our `Views` when our `@Published` properties change. This simple wrapper `View` will retain an instance of `IntGenerator` and update our `EnvironmentValues.int` when our `@Published` property value changes.

```
struct DynamicEnvironmentView<T: View>: View {
    
    private let content: T
    @ObservedObject var intGenerator = IntGenerator()
    
    public init(content: T) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        content
            .environment(\.int, intGenerator.int)
    }
}
```

Let us make it easy to apply this to an entire feature's view hierarchy by creating a custom `UIHostingController` and utilizing our `DynamicEnvironmentView`. This subclass automatically wraps your content inside a `DynamicEnvironmentView`.

```
final class DynamicEnvironmentHostingController<T: View>: UIHostingController<DynamicEnvironmentView<T>> {
    
    public required init(rootView: T) {
        super.init(rootView: DynamicEnvironmentView(content: rootView))
    }
    
    @objc public required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is how we use of new `DynamicHostingController`

```
let contentView = ContentView()
window.rootViewController = DynamicEnvironmentHostingController(rootView: contentView)
```

**Step Three - Pure Swift UI App Approach)** This is if you are using a pure Swift UI app. In this example our `App` retains the reference to the `IntGenerator` but you can play around with different architectures here.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @ObservedObject var intGenerator = IntGenerator()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.int, intGenerator.int)
        }
    }
}
```

**Step Four)** Lastly here is how we actually use our new `EnvironmentKey` in any `View` we need access to the `int`. This `View` will automatically be rebuilt any time the int value updates on our `IntGenerator` class!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.int) var int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("My Int Value: \(int)")
    }
}
```

*Works/Tested in iOS 14 on Xcode 12.2*